# Hide vertical lines between columns in a ListView

Tags: windows, listview, winapi

In Windows 7 with aero theme, the Windows Explorer does not show vertical lines in the details view.

But the Task Manager shows that lines.

Is there a way to hide the vertical lines in a ListView of the Win32 API?

Answer (score 3):

The list view used by Explorer is not the system list view control. Instead it is a private control with class name `DirectUIHWND` that is not exposed for public use.

The system list view control, `SysListView32`, has no options that allow you to suppress the vertical lines between columns in `LVS_REPORT` mode.

Comment: yes, really `DirectUIHWND` in explorer. however are vertical lines exist in ListView report mode - depended from are `SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L"Explorer", 0)` is called for him - by default not exist, with `"Explorer"` theme - exist